# unable to get all fields using CSOM PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, csom

am trying to get all the fields in the  document library in my site collection.
 here is my code . but after entering my username/password , it throws error:

```
       $SiteURL = "http://vmsrvr1:28516/"

     Write-Host "Loading CSOM libraries" -foregroundcolor black -
       backgroundcolor 
      yellow
       Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web 
     Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
      Add-Type -Path "c:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web 
      Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
      Write-Host "Lib. successfully loaded !" -foregroundcolor black -
    backgroundcolor Green 

     $scriptPath = "D:\PoCSolutions"


   $User =    "mydomain\adminuser1" #Read-Host -Prompt "username"
      $password =  Read-Host -Prompt "Enter password" -AsSecureString


      Write-Host "Trying to reach $SiteURL // Handling ClientContext..." -
    foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor yellow  
     $Context = New-Object 
     Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
      $credentials = New-Object 
          Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($User, 
     $password) 
    $Context.Credentials = $credentials 
     $context.RequestTimeOut = 5000 * 60 * 10;
      $web = $context.Web
      $site = $context.Site 
       $context.Load($web)
      $context.Load($site)
       try
       {
          $context.ExecuteQuery()
        Write-Host "Connected !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor 
        Green
       }
       catch
         {
        Write-Host "Impossible to reach $SiteURL : bad password ?" -
       foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Red
           return
          }

   $list = $web.Lists["APT"];
      $fields = $list.Fields;

   $list.Fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path ./blabla.csv;
      Write-Host "Done !" -foregroundcolor black -backgroundcolor Green
```

error is

> New-Object : Exception calling ".ctor" with "2" argument(s): "The 'username' argument is invalid."
>   At E:\PoCSolutions\getallfields1.ps1:18 char:16
>   + $credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredential ...
>   + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [New-Object], MethodInvocationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ConstructorInvokedThrowException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewObjectCommand

[image: username-invalid1]

Answer (score 2):

you are using the SharePoint Online (Office 365) Credential. Thats why your are getting this error.
You are on a SharePoint on-premise, you need to use an other type of Credential.

You should use **[NetworkCredential](https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.networkcredential(v=vs.110).aspx)**

Like :

```
$Context = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL) 
$credentials = New-Object New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($User, $password)
$Context.Credentials = $credentials
```

After, you need to load your fields of your list.
Try something like :

```
$list = $web.Lists.GetByTitle('APT')
$fields = $list.Fields
$context.Load($list)
$context.Load($fields)
$context.ExecuteQuery()

$fields | select InternalName  |  Export-Csv -path ./blabla.csv;
```